# Pushing to a Multidimensional array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use this amazing plugin: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

The problem I'm having is that obviously I need to populate my own data with the following:

```
kwords.push({"value": "0", "name": item.keyword});
```

Firebug is reporting that 'kwords' is not a function (because it's not an array), yet I've copied and pasted the example code on the plugin page as follows:

```
var kwords= {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};
```

So my entire code looks like (and please note this IS an example):

```
var kwords= {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};

kwords.push({"value": "0", "name": item.keyword});

$("#divSelectedKeywords input").autoSuggest(kwords.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
```

(the keyword in the 'item.keyword' is taken from an AJAX call).

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kwords` is an object, thus there should be no `push` method.

What I am assuming you want to do is `kwords.items.push({"value": "0", "name": item.keyword});`, which targets the array named `items`inside the `kwords` object

Comment: of course, I didn't think of like that. Thanks Marco, that makes perfect sense.